# Disable changebar command in the header

Tags: patching

I want to add changebars to toc-entries. It actually works fine but I had to disable the command in the `\mark` commands (so that changebar settles and stops the "rerun" messages in the log-file). The following works but I'm wondering why I have to patch two commands. Why isn't it enough to patch `\markboth`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%must be before babel, as babel redefines markboth:
\patchcmd{\markboth}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\let\cbline\relax}{}{}
\pretocmd{\leftmark}{\let\cbline\relax}{}{}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{changebar}
\newcommand\cbline{}
\DeclareRobustCommand\cbline{\cbstart\cbend}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\leftmark}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section[toc\cbline]{Document}

abc\cbline
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Using `\def` instead of `\let` when patching `\markboth` works:

```
\patchcmd{\markboth}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\def\cbline{}}{}{}
```

But I still don't understand why it is necessary as `\markboth` uses `\let` for label and index command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `\let\cbline\relax`, in a write operation or in an `\edef`, `\cbline` will be written as itself.

So with `\let`, TeX finds again `\cbline` when typesetting the mark and it uses the current definition, which is `\protect\cbline`  which becomes `\cbstart\cbend`.

With `\def\cbline{}`, the `\edef` will make `\cbline` disappear.

Relevant part of the log with `\tracingmacros=1`:

#### With `\def\cbline{}`

```
\@arabic #1->\number #1
#1<-\c@section

\cbline ->

\@themark ->{\protect \foreignlanguage {ngerman}{\protect \bbl@restore@actives
\protect \MakeUppercase  {1\hskip 1em\relax toc}}}{}
```

#### With `\let\cbline\relax`

```
\@arabic #1->\number #1
#1<-\c@section

\@themark ->{\protect \foreignlanguage {ngerman}{\protect \bbl@restore@actives
\protect \MakeUppercase  {1\hskip 1em\relax toc\cbline }}}{}
```

As you see, the latter still has `\cbline`.

Comment: That's one part of the explanation. But what bothered me most was that `\let\label\relax` works as expected in `\markboth`. But I now found the other part: the output routine contains `\let\label\@gobble`.